# Lucene piecewise sort

Tags: java, sorting, lucene

My primary sort is by distance (PointVectorStrategy), base on where (lat/lon) the query is emitted. However, I'd like to sort the first 5 results by a known property (which may be indexed), e.g. revenue. Is there a way to do this?

Example:
Sorted by distance only:

```
lehman brothers
T.J.Maxx
Target
J.P. Morgen
Citi
Dell Computer
Walmart
```

And the desired results:

```
J.P.Morgen
Citi
Target
T.J.Maxx
lehman brothers
Dell Computer
Walmart
```

with the top 5 re-arranged by their revenue.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `lucene search.sort` -- that should help you get going.